# How can I connect the nerves together?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this segmented image with a lot of breaks between the detected nerves as shown in the attached image. How can I connect them together?.

Input image -

[image]

Expected output image -

[image]

Comment: See [related1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26818680/3293881) , [related2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28323143/3293881) , [related3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28393412/3293881).

Comment: Dear Divakar 
I tried this answer before it doesn't work efficiently with my image

Comment: Which question's answer worked for you? How bad is the performance that led you to believe that it's not efficient? What's the expected output image? Answering these by editing the question might inspire us to reopen this question.

Comment: I tried all these answers and there isn't one of them worked efficiently to solve my problem. what I want is to connect the disjoint nerves.

Comment: Sorry, I can't attach the images directly because  of my very poor reputation

Comment: Upload on some public image sharing website and link it here.

Comment: Voting to reopen as OP isn't *happy* with the efficiency of the answers to the linked questions.

Comment: On the left side of the image there are 3 circled connections to be made in a vertical line above each other Looking at the middle one of those 3, how is software supposed to know it joins only one of the two *dangling* nerves and not the other? What's the difference?

Comment: Dear Mark, I'm not worry about the middle circle on the left side of the image, the most important thing is to find efficient way to connect the other nerves. Because the rest of images I don't this case.